# If Condition Stopped After First Statement Execution in C in a Thread

Tags: c, pthreads

I am really having a hard time trying to make a function to loop within a pthread. My function is called by this pthread and it is supposed to loop up to infinite but, it is just not happening. That is why I am asking for help. I created my thread making use of the following code:

```
#include <pthread.h>  
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  

void *thread_s(void *params_s);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int s1_hand = 0;
    pthread_t routines[1];
    printf("Creating Thread -> Main Thread Extremely Busy!\n");

    s1_hand = pthread_create(&(routines[0]), NULL, thread_s, (void *)&(routines[0]));

    if (s1_hand != 0) {
        printf("Not possible to create thread:[%s]\n", strerror(s1_hand));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    void* result;
    if ((pthread_join(routines[0], &result)) == -1) {
        perror("Cannot join S thread");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

And the function I would like to have continuously running is:

```
void *thread_s(void *params_s) {
    printf("Thread starting...\n");
    int fd, chars, pars, c_1, f_parse, pripa = 1;
    fd =  open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0){
        perror("Unable to open the fildes!");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    FILE *stream_a, *stream_b;
    stream_a = fdopen(fd, "r");
    stream_b = fopen(FILE_II, "w+");
    if (stream_a == NULL && stream_b == NULL){
        perror("IMPOSSIBLE TO CREATE STREAMS");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    c_1 = fgetc(stream_a);
    f_parse = lookatit(pripa, c_1, array);
    printf("First Parse Done -> (%i)\n", f_parse);
    while ((chars = fgetc(stream_a)) != EOF){
        pars = lookatit(0, (uint8_t)chars, array);
        if (pars == 1){
            printf("MESSAGE FOUND AND SAVED -> (%i)\n", parsing);
            fprintf(stream_b,"%.6f %.6f %.6f\n", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
        } else{
            printf("Looking for the Message: %i\n", parsing);
            continue;
        }
        chars++;
    }
    fflush(stream_b);
    fclose(stream_b);
    fclose(stream_a);
    close(fd);

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The function "lookatit" performs a parsing routine, returning 1 when a message is found and 0 when no message is found. The function is looping perfectly when no messages are found but, when it finds a message, the if statement (line 22 second code) prints "MESSAGE FOUND AND SAVED" and it immediately terminates the program. Why is my program presenting this behaviour?

Comment: What is the type of `parsing` and where/how is it initialised?

Comment: Might have a segmentation-fault? Have you debugged your application?

Comment: The `char++` statement is weird; the next thing you do is overwrite the incremented value with the result of the next call to `fgetc()`.  Harmless, but mildly worrying...what was meant to happen?  Also, you've not shown a declaration for `parsing` that I can see, but you print it out in the 'Message found and saved' statement and the 'Looking for the message' statement — what is it? Your call to `lookatit()` references `array` but the definition of that is not visible — what is its type and size?  Are you sure it is big enough?  Shouldn't you tell `lookatit()` how big an array it is?

Comment: `if (stream_a == NULL && stream_b == NULL){` that should be `||`, not `&&` - aka, your program should exit if `stream_a` OR `stream_b` are `NULL`

Comment: More than likely, `stream_b` is `NULL`, so the `fprintf` call is segfaulting

Comment: seems like a case for gdb and less so for SO.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks a lot... simonc: I meant pars when writing parsing, sorry about that. It is just an integer value saving either 1 or 0, result coming from "lookatit" function. This function returns 1 if it has found a complete message, filling an array with the values coming from the parsed message, or 0 if no message has been found. Up to now, I have not debugged my application but that is the next step.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler: With the if statement "if (pars == 1){" I am checking if I have received a complete message, if so, then write the values contained in the array filled out by "lookatit" when it finds a complete message to an external file (stream_b). Sorry about Parsing, I just meant Pars.

Comment: segmentation fault? I have not experienced something like that up to now. Thanks for the information, I am going to read much more about the topic. Maybe I am having this problem also...

Comment: Many thanks to @DrewMcGowen. As you told me, I had a segmentation fault error. Thanks to you my program is nicely running :)!!!